# PHP Full search form with select fields

Tags: php, forms, full-text-search

having this problem for more than three days to fix.

I'm creating a form that lets the user search with some conditions.

Why the values of **company and category are not passing to the URL when using the get method**?

```
<form class="main-searchbox-container" role="search" method="get" action="search-results.php">
      <div class="form-group" id="main-searchbox">
           <input id="target" type="text" class="form-control main-search-input" placeholder="Search..." name="target" value="<?php if (isset($_POST['target'])) echo $_POST['target']; ?>" />
      </div>
      <div class="selection-container">
           <select name="company" class="header-selection" form="main-searchbox">
                   <option value="company" name="company">Company</option>
           </select>
      </div>
      <div class="selection-container">
           <select name="category" class="header-selection" form="main-searchbox">
                   <?php 
                    // Make the query:
                    $sql = "select Business_Category from business_categories order by Business_Category ASC";
                    $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
                    if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
                    // output data of each row
                       while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
                                      echo '<option value="'.$row['Business_Category'].'" name="'.$row['Business_Category'].'">'.$row['Business_Category'].'</option>';
                       }
                    } else { echo "----";} // End
                              ?>         
            </select>
        </div>
        <input id="submit" class="btn btn-default main-search-button" type="submit" name="submit" value="Search">
 </form>
```

It must be quite straight forward to fix this and with your feedback can fix that easier.

Thank you for your time.

Comment: Get rid of `form="main-searchbox"` on both as there is not a matching `id` with that name on the `<form>`

Comment: i guess there is no need to give name in options. It only requires in Select tab.

Comment: Yes that also, the name comes from the `<select>`

Comment: thank you, it worked Riggs. God bless

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It worked by removing `form="main-searchbox"` present in both `<select>` elements (inside of `<div class="selection-container">`) as there is not a matching id with that name on the `<form>`, as [RiggsFolly](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2310830/riggsfolly) said in the comments.

See the working code:

```
<form class="main-searchbox-container" role="search" method="get" action="search-results.php">
    <div class="form-group" id="main-searchbox">
        <input id="target" type="text" class="form-control main-search-input" placeholder="Search..." name="target" value="<?php if (isset($_POST['target'])) echo $_POST['target']; ?>" />
    </div>
    <div class="selection-container">
        <select name="company" class="header-selection">
            <option value="company" name="company">Company</option>
        </select>
    </div>
    <div class="selection-container">
        <select name="category" class="header-selection">
            <?php 
                 // Make the query:
                 $sql = "select Business_Category from business_categories order by Business_Category ASC";
                 $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
                 if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
                     // output data of each row
                     while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
                         echo '<option value="'.$row['Business_Category'].'" name="'.$row['Business_Category'].'">'.$row['Business_Category'].'</option>';
                     }
                 } else { echo "----";} // End
            ?>         
            </select>
        </div>
        <input id="submit" class="btn btn-default main-search-button" type="submit" name="submit" value="Search">
 </form>
```